# Is assertEquals JUnit method parameter inversion a big risk?

Tags: java, junit

JUnit specification provides devs with following signature when displaying overloaded asserEquals methods:

```
assertEquals([TYPE] expected, [TYPE] actual)
```

If one logically changes the order of expected parameters in a business context, for example consider:

```
// Class provides correct surname based on name or age etc.
class SurnameProvider {
    static String getSurnameForName(String name) {
        // implementation
    }
} 

@org.junit.Test
public void test() {
    String retrievedSurname = SurnameProvider.getSurnameForName("Vilde");
    String expectedSurname = "Hansen";
    assertEquals(retrievedSurname, expectedSurname); // here expected value is second
}
```

Does order ( actual first and expected second) cause any risks or is highly inappropriate ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The only thing that would change is the failure message.

Comment: The failure message would be different iin case of assertEquals("Hansen", null); and assertEquals(null, "Hansen"); ?

Comment: You should use Asset.isNull().  Makes no sense if you pass a String literal, since it'll always be false.

Comment: I deleted these lines of code as they were misleading and did align with the question topic. Literal testing is not my question.

Comment: @Sinny Of course--the expected and actual values would be reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order affects the error message generated by the JUnit framework when the assertion fails. See the following unit test code:

```
int numberOfHoursPerDay = 2+6*9-5;
Assertions.assertEquals(24, numberOfHoursPerDay);
```

This will generate the following error message:

> expected: <24> but was: <51>

So you can easily see and check: "Hmm, it should be 24, why is it returning 51?". If you change the order like this:

```
int numberOfHoursPerDay = 2+6*9-5;
Assertions.assertEquals(numberOfHoursPerDay, 24);
```

You will get the following message:

> expected: <51> but was: <24>

And now you are thinking: "Hmm, 24 sounds about right, but why should it be 51?" and when you try to fix it you get "Wait, why should it be 38 now? Shouldn't it be 51 as previously? No, wait, it should be 24. What's going on???".

So, changing the order of the values will only confuses **you** and everyone running/using your unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there is any risk about that. And NullPointerException will only happens when you call a method when de-reference a null object, so it should not happen in your example.

However, the code convention is put the expected value before the actual value. This is basically the standard the industry is following.